# c++ base private method can be accessed after casting itself to derived class?

Tags: c++, private, crtp

i found this when I used CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern).

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
private:
    void f() {
        //when T has its own f(), it calls that
        //when T doesn't have, it calls itself, which is invoked recursively
        //but i expect the compiler to complain that f() is private when T doesn't have its own f()
        static_cast<T*>(this)->f();
    }

public:
    void g() {
        f();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
```

I thought i understand `public`, `protected` and `private`, but for this case, it looks like i am wrong. Any explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the shadowing declaration is `public`. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/XSQRkR):

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
private:
    void f() { }
};

void x(Derived* d) {
    d->g();
}
```

You get:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void Base<T>::f() [with T = Derived]':
<source>:13:9:   required from 'void Base<T>::g() [with T = Derived]'
<source>:23:10:   required from here
<source>:8:9: error: 'void Derived::f()' is private within this context
         static_cast<T*>(this)->f();
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:10: note: declared private here
     void f() { }
          ^
```

If the function is not shadowed in `Derived`, the call is the same as `this->Base<Derived>::f()`, which has to be legal, as `Base` is the only class that can access it.

It's also possible that your confusion came from accessing a seemingly different object. Keep in mind that access modifiers restrict access by scope, not by instance. Any method declared in `Base` can touch *any* `Base` instance's private members, not just `this`'s.

Comment: I think I understand if you put private there, it will trigger that complain. What confused me is that after i cast `this` to `Derived` type, as `f()`is private to `Derived`, why it can access `f()`?

Comment: If `f()` is defined in `Derived` as a private method, then it doesn't work, as the example shows. If `f()` is not shadowed, then there is no problem because `f()` is a private member of `Base`. `Derived` is unable to access it: if `Base` couldn't, then nothing would be able to use it. The fact that the compiler has static knowledge that the object is a `Derived` does not changes access rules: otherwise, you could circumvent that check by casting your `Derived` to a `Base`, which wouldn't be very effective access control.

Comment: Thanks for your following up. But i am sorry, i still don't understand. 1. could you help me with an example to explain that `otherwise, you could circumvent that check by casting your Derived to a Base, which wouldn't be very effective access control`?  2. how is `static_cast<T*>(this)->f();` is same as `this->Base<Derived>::f()` when `Derived` doesn't have `f()`? for me, we will get `Derived` pointer after `static_cast<T*>(this)`, since it's `Derived` type, the compiler should check that `f()` is invisible to this type and then fail.

Comment: @goldenretriever, you've probably made your example more complex than you need by including CRTP; the rules all hold for any `Base` and `Derived : Base` class pair. For point 1: `static_cast<Base*>(static_cast<Derived*>(this))->f()`. For point 2: `Derived` does not declare an `f()` and the only declaration of it is `Base::f`, which is accessible by any member of `Base`. `Base::f()` does not get "renamed" to `Derived::f()` by mere virtue of inheritance: `Derived` can't access `f()` at all, after all.

Comment: i understand `Base::f, which is accessible by any member of Base`. But doesn't `static_cast<Derived*>(this)` make it a `Derive*` type? is this correct? if this's correct, then how `Derived*` access `f()`, to me, it should failed by compiler?

Comment: also i think CRTP is needed, it gives the way to cast `Base` back to `Derived`

Comment: @goldenretriever, `static_cast<T*>` doesn't change the nature of the object that is being pointed to. Besides, access control is not applied by the object that you try to access: it's applied by the scope. Any method of `Base` can access any member of the `Base` class, and any member of any instance of it. See [this other example](https://godbolt.org/z/unfkvU) that doesn't use CRTP and let me know if it clears up anything or if it helps you formulate your question in terms that don't involve CRTP.